# How to calculate row count with Not operation without hardcoding in SQL/Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Considering 2 columns upon joining the table: Drugname & PT. How can I calculate "The number of primary case reports involving NOT Drugname X and PT".
For Ex: PT='Nausea' then I want all the drugs names and the number of row counts involving NOT Drugname X and PT='Nausea'.

EX: PREDNISONE | 20

That means there are 20 rows in the table having Nausea but NOT Drugname as PREDNISONE.

Snowflake Code:

```
select distinct DRUGNAME, count(PT) as c from DRUG join REACTION
on"DRUG".PRIMARYID = "REACTION".PRIMARYID
where PT ='Nausea' and DRUGNAME != DRUGNAME
group by DRUGNAME
```

However this is giving me 0 rows looks like instead of checking DRUGNAME != DRUGNAME for individual row/cell, it is looking for entire column.
How to solve this without hardcoding? can't list all the names since there are 4k drugnames.

Comment: `DRUGNAME != DRUGNAME ` is always FALSE so now row will be in the resultset

Comment: are you sure drug.primaryid should equal reaction.primaryid?

Comment: Yes @Kurt drug.primaryid is the equal reaction.primaryid, however there are duplicates.

Comment: @nbk DRUGNAME != DRUGNAME  is always FALSE, my question is how to check it row wise instead looking into whole column?

Comment: @Manoj can you please send us the Explain plan of the query, this will give an idea what is Snowflake doing to execute the query. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/explain.html

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] because I can't understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subquery to get the count itself, so that you can compare the drug name from your join separately from the distinct drug you're considering for the output row. Something like this:

```
select DISTINCT DRUGNAME,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM DRUG 
      join REACTION
        on "DRUG".PRIMARYID = "REACTION".PRIMARYID
      WHERE PT='Nausea'
        AND DRUG.DRUGNAME != DISTINCT_DRUG.DRUGNAME
    ) as c
from DRUG AS DISTINCT_DRUG
```

Comment: @ StriplingWarrior this query is taking forever to run!

Comment: @ManojKashyap: Sorry. I assumed Snowflake would optimize the query well, and I didn't have a data set to test it on. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to structure the query, but it's hard for me to know which will be best without being able to test it on representative data.